# Passing input value from one form to another in the same php page with jquery, ending with all values lost when submit the second form

Tags: jquery, html

i'm triying to pass a value from one form to another in the same php page through jquery.
The data pass correctly, but when i submit the second form with method post, i lost all the values.
Thanks in advance.

```
<form id="form1">
   <input name="producto" type="text">
   <button id="cd-cart-trigger" type="button">GO</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
      var form1 = $('#form1'), 
          form2 = $('#form2');  

      $('#cd-cart-trigger').click(function(){
        $(':input[name]', form2).val(function(){
          return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
        });
      });
    });
</script>

<form id="form2" action="sender.php" method="post">
   <input name="producto" type="text"/>
   <input class="side_form_button" type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Comment: Java -- are you sure? That looks much more like JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, it looks more like jquery.

Comment: sorry, i'm a newbie... editing right now